# Como debo crear los campos de una colección de Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, flutter

Estoy intentando agregar los campos de la colección "emails" de este json

```
{
"from": {
  "email": "hello@mailersend.com",
  "name": "MailerSend"
},
"to": [
  {
    "email": "john@mailersend.com",
    "name": "John Mailer"
  }
],
"subject": "Hello from {$company}!",
"text": "This is just a friendly hello from your friends at {$company}.",
"html": "<b>This is just a friendly hello from your friends at {$company}.</b>",
"variables": [
  {
    "email": "john@mailersend.com",
    "substitutions": [
      {
        "var": "company",
        "value": "MailerSend"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

}

Estoy tratando de configurar "Firebase integration with MailerSend"

En: https://www.mailersend.com/integrations/firebase

Gracias por la ayuda